# HP Pavilion tx2514 wacom convertible tablet "Wacom ISDv4 93 Pen stylus" won't reveal launcher

Tags: launcher, tablet, wacom

I have installed the latest drivers.

I also tried increasing launcher sensitivity using "CompizConfig Settings Manager" and to adjust pressure sensitivity.

I would like to use my laptop in tablet mode, but can't without turning off auto hide launcher.

I would like some real space when working in tablet mode.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround for my problem.

If you use "Onboard", you can reveal the Launcher with the Super key.

You can still auto-hide Onboard, and if you set it to show notification icon, and set it to auto-show when editing text the keyboard will reveal. From there you can press the Super key to reveal the Launcher.